# Wxsmith how to make WxGrid infinite rows

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to keep writing data into WxGrid, but i need to set the rows for WxGrid. I've searched some way but the answer that i get is to use Wx.GridTableBase which is for WxPython.
Is there any way to make WxGrid rows infinite? 
I'm using codeblocks c++ with WxSmith.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in any of the RAD tool. Just call `AddRow()` in your code.

Comment: `infinite` rows? I assume what you mean is as you scroll down to show more and more rows, which you can do by adding rows by tracking the scroll. But that will be quite work...

Comment: @macroland How can i adding rows to WxGrid? i tried using AddRow but it gives me error `'class wxGrid' has no member named 'AddRow'`. Do i need to use `CreateGrid` to add row?

Comment: Please spare your time to look at the manuals!!! https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_grid.html#a33a482af1a30ac07d3bfd6154e8a6045

Comment: @macroland Sorry, my bad, i should've used `appendrows`. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i just need to use `AppendRows()` everytime i need to add rows. it's on the manuals https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_grid.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have a lot of data in your grid, it is much better (i.e. more efficient) to define your own grid table, i.e. a class deriving from [wxGridTableBase](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_grid_table_base.html), and store your data there.